# lisp error handling - check if variable nil

Tags: loops, for-loop, foreach, common-lisp

I've been recently dealing with some lisp, I am writing a function, which returns combinations of elements. It works nice, but it still throws me a warning error > Argument Y is not a NUMBER: NIL

my CODE:

```
(defun printo (x y z)
  (if (and x y z)      
      (format t "~a and ~a  difference: ~a ~%" x y z)
      ))

(defun getDiff (x y)
  (return-from getDiff (abs (- x y))))


(defun distcalc (lista)
  (loop for k from 0 to (list-length lista)
     do (loop for j from 0 to (list-length lista)
       do (let ((pivot (nth k lista))(base (nth j lista)))
        (if (nth j lista)(printo  pivot  base (abs (- base pivot))
                      ))
        ))
       ))

(distcalc '(1 10 20 25 13))
```

As I am a beginner in this, I think I might have missed some error handling somewhere, but slime throwing me on that error screen is really annoying!

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please use standard formatting and naming:

```
(defun printo (x y z)
  (if (and x y z)
      (format t "~a and ~a  difference: ~a ~%" x y z)))

(defun get-diff (x y)
  (return-from get-diff (abs (- x y))))

(defun distcalc (lista)
  (loop for k from 0 to (list-length lista)
        do (loop for j from 0 to (list-length lista)
                 do (let ((pivot (nth k lista))
                          (base (nth j lista)))
                      (if (nth j lista)
                          (printo pivot base (abs (- base pivot))))))))

(distcalc '(1 10 20 25 13))
```

If you do not need the alternative in an `if`, use `when`:

```
(defun printo (x y z)
  (when (and x y z)
    (format t "~a and ~a  difference: ~a ~%" x y z)))

(defun get-diff (x y)
  (return-from get-diff (abs (- x y))))

(defun distcalc (lista)
  (loop for k from 0 to (list-length lista)
        do (loop for j from 0 to (list-length lista)
                 do (let ((pivot (nth k lista))
                          (base (nth j lista)))
                      (when (nth j lista)
                        (printo pivot base (abs (- base pivot))))))))

(distcalc '(1 10 20 25 13))
```

You do not need to `return` or `return-from`; a function body returns the
values of the last form.  I guess that you want to use your `get-diff`:

```
(defun printo (x y z)
  (when (and x y z)
    (format t "~a and ~a  difference: ~a ~%" x y z)))

(defun get-diff (x y)
  (abs (- x y)))

(defun distcalc (lista)
  (loop for k from 0 to (list-length lista)
        do (loop for j from 0 to (list-length lista)
                 do (let ((pivot (nth k lista))
                          (base (nth j lista)))
                      (when (nth j lista)
                        (printo pivot base (get-diff base pivot)))))))

(distcalc '(1 10 20 25 13))
```

The error is that looping `to` includes the end; you want `below`:

```
(defun printo (x y z)
  (when (and x y z)
    (format t "~a and ~a  difference: ~a ~%" x y z)))

(defun get-diff (x y)
  (abs (- x y)))

(defun distcalc (lista)
  (loop for k from 0 below (list-length lista)
        do (loop for j from 0 below (list-length lista)
                 do (let ((pivot (nth k lista))
                          (base (nth j lista)))
                      (when (nth j lista)
                        (printo pivot base (get-diff base pivot)))))))

(distcalc '(1 10 20 25 13))
```

However, you do not need the indices at all, so you can simply loop over the list:

```
(defun printo (x y z)
  (when (and x y z)
    (format t "~a and ~a  difference: ~a ~%" x y z)))

(defun get-diff (x y)
  (abs (- x y)))

(defun distcalc (lista)
  (loop for pivot in lista
        do (loop for base in lista
                 when base
                 do (printo pivot base (get-diff base pivot)))))

(distcalc '(1 10 20 25 13))
```

We can now perhaps better see that any `nil`s in `lista` would also be a
problem in the outer loop:

```
(defun printo (x y z)
  (when (and x y z)
    (format t "~a and ~a  difference: ~a ~%" x y z)))

(defun get-diff (x y)
  (abs (- x y)))

(defun distcalc (lista)
  (loop for pivot in lista
        when pivot
        do (loop for base in lista
                 when base
                 do (printo pivot base (get-diff base pivot)))))

(distcalc '(1 10 20 25 13))
```

Comment: Darn, thanks for the thorough answer, this certainly helps with my lisp!

Comment: Sorry to write again, but if I am trying to collect the differences, the collect command doesn't output any list. What could be wrong here?

Comment: @sdgawerzswer maybe ask new question, with the updated code and the new problem?

Comment: I figured it out already, the key was to collect in both loops.

Answer (score 3):

Your error is that `(loop for k from 0 to (list-length lista))` will give you `k` `0-5`, not `0-4`. `(nth 5 '(1 10 20 25 13))` will give you `nil` and `(- 1 nil)` the same error. doing `nth` every time is not good. you should perhaps instead do:

```
(defun distcalc (lista)
  (loop :for pivot :in lista
        :do (loop :for base :in lista
                  :if base
                  :do (printo pivot base (abs (- base pivot))))))
```